# Expression Too Complex In Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

When I try to run this query in Access through the ODBC interface into a MySQL database I get an "Expression too complex in query expression" error. The essential thing I'm trying to do is translate abbreviated names of languages into their full body English counterparts. I was curious if there was some way to "trick" access into thinking the expression is smaller with sub queries, or if someone else had a better idea of how to solve this problem. I thought about making a temporary table and doing a join on it, but that's not supported in Access SQL.

Just as an FYI, the query worked fine until I added the big long IFF chain. I tested the query on a smaller IFF chain for three languages, and that wasn't an issue, so the problem definitely stems from the huge IFF chain (It's 26 deep). Also, I might be able to drop some of the options (like combining the different forms of Chinese or Portuguese)

As a test, I was able to get the SQL query to work after paring it down to 14 IFF() statements, but that's a far cry from the 26 languages I'd like to represent.

```
SELECT TOP 5 Count( * ) AS [Number of visits by language], IIf(login.lang="ar","Arabic",IIf(login.lang="bg","Bulgarian",IIf(login.lang="zh_CN","Chinese (Simplified Han)",IIf(login.lang="zh_TW","Chinese (Traditional Han)",IIf(login.lang="cs","Czech",IIf(login.lang="da","Danish",IIf(login.lang="de","German",IIf(login.lang="en_US","United States English",IIf(login.lang="en_GB","British English",IIf(login.lang="es","Spanish",IIf(login.lang="fr","French",IIf(login.lang="el","Greek",IIf(login.lang="it","Italian",IIf(login.lang="ko","Korean",IIf(login.lang="hu","Hungarian",IIf(login.lang="nl","Dutch",IIf(login.lang="pl","Polish",IIf(login.lang="pt_PT","European Portuguese",IIf(login.lang="pt_BR","Brazilian Portuguese",IIf(login.lang="ru","Russian",IIf(login.lang="sk","Slovak",IIf(login.lang="sl","Slovenian","IIf(login.lang="fi","Finnish",IIf(login.lang="sv","Swedish",IIf(login.lang="tr","Turkish","Unknown")))))))))))))))))))))))))) AS [Language]
FROM login, reservations, reservation_users, schedules
WHERE (reservations.start_date Between DATEDIFF('s','1970-01-01 00:00:00',[Starting Date in the Following Format YYYY/MM/DD]) And DATEDIFF('s','1970-01-01 00:00:00',[Ending Date in the Following Format YYYY/MM/DD])) And reservations.is_blackout=0 And reservation_users.memberid=login.memberid And reservation_users.resid=reservations.resid And reservation_users.invited=0 And reservations.scheduleid=schedules.scheduleid And scheduletitle=[Schedule Title]
GROUP BY login.lang
ORDER BY Count( * ) DESC;
```

@ Michael Todd

I completely agree. The list of languages should have been a table in the database and the login.lang should have been a FK into that table. Unfortunately this isn't how the database was written, and it's not really mine to modify. The languages are placed into the login.lang field by the PHP running on top of the database.

Comment: Why not just use a lookup table with the language values, then join it in your query? It needn't be a temporary table (in fact, it probably should be a permanent one).

Comment: I completely agree with Michael Todd. It should be very easy indeed to set up a table with language abbreviation and full name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about making a temporary table and doing a join on it, but that's not supported in Access SQL.

Did you try making a table of languages within Access, and joining it to the MySQL tables?

Comment: Just today, and yes that worked perfectly :) I didn't have the modify the original database.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below expression. what I did is, your expression is cut down to two parts, then a final 'IIf' check will do the trick. You will have additional 2 fields and you may ignore those. I had the same situation and this worked well for me. PS: You may need to double check the closing brackets in the below expression. I did it quickly.

Thanks,
Shibin

```
IIf(login.lang="ar","Arabic",IIf(login.lang="bg","Bulgarian",IIf(login.lang="zh_CN","Chinese (Simplified Han)",IIf(login.lang="zh_TW","Chinese (Traditional Han)",IIf(login.lang="cs","Czech",IIf(login.lang="da","Danish",IIf(login.lang="de","German",IIf(login.lang="en_US","United States English",IIf(login.lang="en_GB","British English",IIf(login.lang="es","Spanish",IIf(login.lang="fr","French",IIf(login.lang="el","Greek",IIf(login.lang="it","Italian",""))))))))))))) as l1, 

IIf(login.lang="ko","Korean",IIf(login.lang="hu","Hungarian",IIf(login.lang="nl","Dutch",IIf(login.lang="pl","Polish",IIf(login.lang="pt_PT","European Portuguese",IIf(login.lang="pt_BR","Brazilian Portuguese",IIf(login.lang="ru","Russian",IIf(login.lang="sk","Slovak",IIf(login.lang="sl","Slovenian","IIf(login.lang="fi","Finnish",IIf(login.lang="sv","Swedish",IIf(login.lang="tr","Turkish","Unknown")))))))))))) as l2,

IIf(l1="",l2,l1) AS [Language]
```

Comment: This is a terrible suggestion -- it's storing data in your SQL statement. -1

Comment: @ David-W-Fenton: It's depend on situation, I had a situation where I was limited to create new table due to extremely complex IIf conditions and other reasons. I gave this suggestion as in the question it is also mentioned "I completely agree. The list of languages should have been a table in the database and the login.lang should have been a FK into that table. Unfortunately this isn't how the database was written, and it's not really mine to modify." Read the question fully before judging something "terrible"

Comment: I don't see any reason that the original database would need to be modified. The number of rows in the lookup table is not enough to cause a performance issue, and, of course, compared to encoding the lookup values in the SQL, it couldn't possibly be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Shibin. I think Catcall found the "right" solution, but it's at least interesting to know that there's a workaround for Access's "expression too complex" error. At the very least, this might be helpful for someone else who was not trying to "use SQL the wrong way" but just has a query that's too complicated, and still wants Access to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a lookup table, create a custom VB function, so that instead of 26 IIf statements, you have one function call.