# Expression too Complex Error while using complicated IIF Condition Statements- Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, switch-statement, iif

Im getting a query error in MS Access "Expression too Complex in query expression". I have a bunch of nested IIF statements with complex Conditional Statements, i have about 23 of these total and currently im on 13 when it started breaking.

A common resolution i've seen is to create a seperate lookup table housing the values to be returned but i dont think this will work in my case since i have complex boolean logic.

I've researched the issue and i believe using SWITCH statement will cause the same issue. 
Someone from another post suggested to break the IIF statement into 2 parts and then a 3rd final IIF to compare the two but havent given it a shot yet.
[Expression Too Complex In Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568488/expression-too-complex-in-access-2007)

```
iif( (HedgeFile.[UnwindDate] is Not Null OR HedgeFile.[UnwindDate] <> '') AND (HedgeFile.[UnwindDate] <= 12/31/2018 AND  HedgeFile.[Current Base Rate] = 0), '2. Terminated', 
iif (HedgeFile.[Port] IN ('ASSUME', 'HDLTV'), '3. Port Excluded from Model',
iif (HedgeFile.[Code] = 'WSP', '4. Company Swaps', 'OK') AS FilterName
```

If anyone has any advice on how to tackle this, please advise. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Unless you need to run this query outside of Access, I would create a VBA function for that. Feed it all input parameters (UnwindDate, Port, Code, ...), and it returns the value. Additional advantage: you can write readable and maintainable code.

Comment: I would go the VBA route but unfortunately, this code will be converted to Oracle SQL once complete and working. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: _ code will be converted to Oracle SQL_. Then you will have to convert it anyway. As @Andre suggests, use VBA, it won't fail.

Comment: Converting it wont be my responsibility, i will be doing a hand off and it has to be in SQL format.

Comment: Then you are left with Switch - which you believe will cause the same issue.

Comment: Ended up breaking the IIF statement into 2 parts and then a 3rd final IIF to compare the two, works like  charm. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Improper parens.
If UnwindDate is a date/time field, need delimiters for the date parameter. If it is text type then need apostrophe delimiters. If it is a date/time type then field cannot hold a string so checking for string is not needed and might cause data type mismatch error. If field is text type then handle possible null or empty string with: `HedgeFile.UnwindDate & "" <> ""` (I never allow empty string in tables).

```
IIf(Not HedgeFile.[UnwindDate] Is Null AND HedgeFile.[UnwindDate] <= #12/31/2018# AND HedgeFile.[Current Base Rate] = 0, '2. Terminated', 
IIf(HedgeFile.[Port] IN ('ASSUME', 'HDLTV'), '3. Port Excluded from Model',
IIf(HedgeFile.[Code] = 'WSP', '4. Company Swaps', 'OK'))) AS FilterName
```

or

```
Switch(Not HedgeFile.[UnwindDate] Is Null AND HedgeFile.[UnwindDate] <= #12/31/2018# AND HedgeFile.[Current Base Rate] = 0, '2. Terminated', 
HedgeFile.[Port] IN ('ASSUME', 'HDLTV'), '3. Port Excluded from Model',
HedgeFile.[Code] = 'WSP', '4. Company Swaps', TRUE, 'OK') AS FilterName
```

Answer (score 0):

I Ended up breaking the IIF Statement into parts as i suggested in my Original Question.